# Google query multiple columns references

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I have this query:
`=QUERY(all!A:Z, "select B where (B=1 and H=true)")`

How can I turn `B` and `H` into a column reference so I don't have to write them when I copy the query to new cells.

Note: column B is a number, meanwhile H contains boolean values.

Answer (score 1):

try it like this:

```
=QUERY({all!A:Z}, "select Col2 where (Col2=1 and Col8=true)")
```